# How to access dynamic form name in Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to access the dynamic form name in controller. Here is my code:

*HTML*

```
<form name="{{myForm}}" novalidate>     
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" required/>
    <span ng-show="(submit && myForm.username.$error.required)">
        <span>Required</span>
    </span>
</form>
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.myForm= "validateForm";      
    console.log("form" + $scope.myForm)
});
```

I want $scope.myForm should print the form object but it prints the string "validateForm"

Comment: Did you try `$scope.name`?

Comment: Sorry it's typing mistake actually it's <form name="{{myForm}}" novalidate>

Comment: Well, you wrote `$scope.myForm = "validateForm";`. What exactly did you expect that `$scope.myForm` would print actually? Something different from `validateForm`? Because if it was something different then I would be puzzled. Wouldn't you?

Comment: I want it should print the form object not "validateForm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you wanted to validated dynamic form without knowing its name. 
You could pass a `form` name on form `submit` event `ng-submit`

```
<form name="{{name}}" novalidate ng-submit="save(name)">
```

Then you could validate form inside controller method.

```
$scope.save = function(form){
   console.log($scope[form]) //here you can get form from `$scope`
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution but it's not printing the form object.. it just printing the string name attibute

Comment: @Vinothkanna check updated.. forgot to update code in my function.. It should be `$scope[form]`

Comment: Is there any other way to do it other than this?

Comment: @Vinothkanna what do you mean by anyother way & why this isn't good?

Comment: This is good when we have a submit button inside the same form but in my case i have lots of components. I have a buttons in a seperate component so ng-submit is not triggered

Comment: @Vinothkanna could you open new question with more information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587057/how-to-access-unknown-form-in-controller