# How to access unknown form in controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have more than three dynamically generated forms. I need to iterate all the errors of the forms in controller. I am assigning form names by using models.

```
<form name="{{myForm}}" novalidate>     
<input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" required/>
<span ng-show="(submit && myForm.username.$error.required)">
    <span>Required</span>
</span>
```

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope) {
$scope.myForm= "validateForm";      
console.log("form" + $scope.myForm)
});
```

What I want is when I console `$scope.myForm` it should print the form object but what happens is it just prints the `"validateForm"` string.

Comment: try this `console.log("form" + $scope[$scope.myForm])`

Comment: `$scope.myForm` should be `$scope.myForm = angular.element('[name="validateForm"]')`

Comment: @RichardMauritz OP is looking for the validation object...not an element. Should never have dom search code in a controller either. That is a very backwards approach to working in angular. And `angular.element` doesn't support that selector

Comment: console.log("form" + $scope[$scope.myForm]) I am getting undefined in console. pls give some other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You ultimately want `$scope.validateForm` since `"validateForm"` is the name you give to the form once `name="{{myForm}}"` is compiled:

Can get it from `$scope[$scope.myForm]`

Note that this won't be available in controller until after the view is compiled first time and the validation object is created during the compile process

All you are currently doing is logging a primitive that you assigned on the previous line

Comment: Hi it's not working i am getting undefined in console

Comment: actually will need to use an event or a watch ... controller runs before view is compiled and that validation object gets initialized then